# Using KAFKA as Hot storage and MySQL as Cold Storage

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

I want to insert around 500k datas per second into KAFKA, and then synchronize them with `MySQL` database that support only 40k INSERTs/UPDATEs per second.

So in order to acheive my goal, i want use `KAFKA` as a hot storage since i need to use the datas as fast as possible and share them with multiple services and make updates quickly since it can't be done using `MySQL` alone (That i want to use as a cold storage to store the datas as long as possible and archive the changes).

Here a schema about my need:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NTY2.jpg

Is there any idea on how to process this case ? Or another way to acheive the same goal ?

I don't need a code but a ressources and path to follow (My main language is PHP).

Comment: check out kafka-connect, btw kafka and php are not going together well.

Comment: @Ntwobike Kafka connect reflect changes from database to KAFKA ... and my goal is to insert/update details from kafka to mysql. There is a kafka client for PHP, but this not a problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka connect JDBC acts as both a source **and** a sink. Therefore it can at least perform inserts, and updates might depend upon your Kafka message structure / primary keys in the table

Comment: Inserts are performed realtime ? If MySQL server go down, insert will be performed when it go online or it get lost ? And what do you mean about UPDATEs ? This is not possible or ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's performed in batches. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#writes  And if the database is down, then messages are not sent, and Connect will fail/stop until restarted manually. Meanwhile, the Kafka Consumer lag will increase and messages are still produced to the topic, but nothing is lost until the messages are actually dropped from the topic.

Comment: So as soon as the server go live, all not sent messages will be sent again - What about UPDATEs please ?

Comment: And finally can kafka connect jdbc will work on Windows ?

Comment: The documentation mentioned upserts. I have no experience with it, personally, and I haven't used any Kafka services on Windows, but Kafka Connect does have a bat script to start it up